# Is there a way to generate CRUD actions dynamically for my domain objects?

Tags: isis

By following the Apache Isis tutorial I had generate the "myApp" application that I'm using to studies purposes.

One thing that I noticed as a surprise is that any action over the domain object need to be predetermined with static inner classes.

I found this very verbose for simple CRUD operations and I looked all over the Apache isis documentation site section and found no way for generating dynamic actions for CRUD operations.

Is there a way to do that?
Do I really need to write inner classes for every action that I want for my domain object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, no.  Those nested static classes are for if you want to generate type-safe domain events that can then be subscribed to by other objects via the internal event bus.  Sorry if that's not clear.

To write an action, just write a public method, eg:

```
public Order placeOrder(Product p, int quantity) { ... }
```

If all you want is CRUD, then there's no need to write any actions; objects have an edit mode and the user can just change any field.

For more sophisticated apps we usually suggest that is disabled using @DomainObject(editing=Editing.DISABLED) - or it can be disabled globally for all objects using a setting in the isis.properties configuration file - and write an action to better capture the intent of the user's change to the data.

Going back to those nested static classes, if you *do* want an event to be generated, then you can annotate it, eg:

```
public static class PlaceOrderEvent extends ActionDomainEvent {}
@Action(domainEvent=PlaceOrderEvent.class)
public Order placeOrder(Product p, int quantity) { ... }
```

this then lets other code subscribe using, eg:

```
@Subscribe public void on(Customer.PlaceOrderEvent ev) { ... }
```

These can be used to veto actions (eg referential integrity at the domain layer) or to perform triggers (eg cascade updates or denormalized data).  But those are advanced use cases; generally speaking that sort of stuff gets added later on.

Hope that helps.  For other questions, I recommend you subscribe to the users mailing list, we tend to pick up on questions there faster than here on SO.

Thx